# Apple Sign not working with expo react native in TestFlight and Apple send me a review

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

My apple sign in work fine on Expo Go and Simulator but when i want to connect with TestFlight, nothing happens. So Apple send me a review that : " We discovered one or more bugs in your app. Specifically, the app stays on the login screen when attempting to log in using Sign in with Apple. ". I don't know why this happen.
My code :

```
const loginWithApple = () => {
        const nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);

        return Crypto.digestStringAsync(Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256, nonce)
            .then((hashedNonce) =>
                AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
                    requestedScopes: [
                        AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                        AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL
                    ],
                    nonce: hashedNonce
                })
            )
            .then(async (appleCredential) => {
                const { identityToken } = appleCredential;
                const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
                const credential = await provider.credential({
                    idToken: identityToken,
                    rawNonce: nonce
                });
                await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((res) => {
                    const profileInfo = res.user.providerData[0];
                    const uid = res.user.uid;
                    let action = addUserOnFirestore(
                        uid,
                        profileInfo.email,
                        profileInfo.displayName?.split(" ")[0],
                        profileInfo.displayName?.split(" ")[2],
                        profileInfo.photoURL,
                        res,
                        props.navigation
                    );

                    setIsLoading(true);
                    try {
                        dispatch(action);
                    } catch (err) {
                        setError(err.message);
                    }
                    setIsLoading(false);
                });
                // Successful sign in is handled by firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error : ', error);
            });
    }
```

Did I missing something ? Thanks to all in advance.